# multiserverthread for two different type of client

Tags: java

I create a multiserverthread that receives request from two dfferent type of clients es. A and B.
If client A sends a request the server has to make some tasks while If the server receives request from B execute other tasks. I have to implement two different type of server or simply two different type of thread with obviously different method run()?

Comment: requests are requests, doesn't matter what type clients they are coming from.

Comment: I have to implement two different type of server class or simply two different type of thread with obviously different method run()

Comment: But if I create an unique server thread I have only one method run(). How can I make the difference between request came from A or B?

Comment: @Mazzy let's suppose you have two methods named: `incrementValue` and `decrementValue`. If you want to call `incrementValue` every time a request from A is received and call `decrementValue` every time a request from B is received, then each client has to identify themselves along with the request they make. The clients can send an identification message like: "I am client A" or "I am client B', then your server can call the appropriate method.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `interface` and  implement that in your `ServerClasses`

ie,

```
interface BasicServer{
  void performClientTasks();
}
```

Now implement this in your ServerClasses

```
 class YourFirstServer extends ..... implements BasicServer{

 ..........
 void performClientTasks(){
 //STUFF FOR FIRST SERVER
 }
```

Now next Server class

```
 class YourSecondServer extends ..... implements BasicServer{

 ..........
 void performClientTasks(){
 //STUFF FOR Second SERVER
 }
```

Now Keep a reference of Interface where you want object...ie,

```
BasicServer myserver;
```

Now allocate correct object when you want:::

```
if(CLIENT1_IS_THERE){
//ACTIVATE FIRSTSERVER
myserver = new YourFirstServer();
}
else
{
//NOW CLIENT2 IS THERE.SO ACTIVATE SECONDSERVER
myserver = new YourSecondServer();
}
```

Now when you want to perform task

I think it was in run method..then,

```
void run(){

//JUST CALL
myserver.performClientTasks();
}
```

*This call will make it work correctly as `performClientTasks()` method will work according to the object inside `myserver`.*

You can add in the `interface` and implement as many methods as you want...I just gave you a sample...But you should remember that lines in italics

Hope this may help you..